# How can I reuse an Xcode project for other similar Apps?

Tags: xcode

I've created an app which plays various sequences of soundclips according to user selections. I want to create a few apps using the same user interface and code, but with separate sound clips and some different graphics in the other apps. What is the best way to save the project to use the code again as a template in different apps please? 
I read about creating a new target, but don't really understand this or whether this would be the right thing to do?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a different target for each of your several apps and include different resources in each one. Each 'target' in Xcode creates some product, so if you want 4 different apps to be generated you'd create 4 different targets, one for each app. Use the Target Membership section of the File Inspector to choose which target each of your files belongs to. There's also an aggregate target to which you can add other targets; building the aggregate target would cause all the targets it depends on to be built. That'd let you build all of your apps at once.

Comment: Thank you - please can someone direct me to a guide on creating targets - a guide I found said it can be done by finding targets in the groups panel, but I cannot find this in xcode 4 - I really appreciate any guidance - thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need to know beyond `File->New...->Target...`?

Comment: Basically when I create the new target, a new folder is created with the name I gave the target and also one with the extension 'Tests'. The new folder has AppDelegate.h & .m inside, however as it doesn't have the files with code in from the main app, I don't understand how I would for example change a label in a window in the main storyboard for the second app, or just for the new target reference another sound file. Thanks for any help - I'm new to this.

Comment: Individual files can't have different content for different targets. If you want the main storyboard to be different, you'll need to make a copy of it and add the copy to your new target instead of the original. Then you can change it however you like. You can probably do some conditional compilation with `#if/#endif` in your source code to handle different targets, but I'd avoid that if possible.

Comment: Thank you - so if copy the storyboard to the target file, do I also need to copy the other files with the code in to the target, or will they be connected from the original? If they don't need to be copied, then how would I reference different audio files from the different targets?

Comment: No, if the files are common to several targets you just add them to each target as I described in the answer above. Select the file and look for the Target Membership section in the inspector -- then check the box next to each target that you want the file to belong to.

Comment: Is it possible to copy the files directly from the main project into the target? I have tried but not succeeded. When I select a file there is no option to copy it? Sorry if there is an obvious way to do this, but I haven't found it.

Comment: @user2062943 If you really want to duplicate a file, you can copy it in the Finder, name it appropriately, and add the new file to your project. If you're not planning on changing it, though, you don't need to copy anything. Targets don't "contain" files -- they just reference files in the project. Example: file `foo.m` might be used in 3 different targets -- there's no need to make a separate copy for each.

Comment: Thanks again - that is really helpful - hopefully just one more question. I added the files via Finder, however in the xcode file navigation pane they don't show up. I presume I keep the filenames the same so if they are in the target folder they will override the reference to the original file? I have closed down Xcode and restarted etc, but still can't find them. I'd really appreciate any advice please.

Comment: Just to update, I've worked out how to add the files but have another problem. I am trying to get this to work with an app where I wanted to  just change some text in labels, so I added a copy of the main storyboard to the target and edited the labels. I didn't add any other files to the target as I wanted to keep everything else the same, however when I test the target I just get a blank screen - any suggestions about anything I might need to do please? Thanks